# An error occurred when downloading files from web using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to the Python.I was trying to download a file from a website.This is the URL of the file I need http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
I run my code many times.It alwys works.But sometimes an error will occurr.
Here is my code

```
import requests


url = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True,timeout=5)
```

I learned this from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/downloading-files-from-web-using-python.
The Traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1371, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 280, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 447, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='yann.lecun.com', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jojo\source\repos\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5.py", line 9, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True,timeout=5)
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jojo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='yann.lecun.com', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
```

I think it is a network connection error,but I am not sure.If so,how could I avoid it?
SORRY FOR THIS SILLY QUESTION!!!

Comment: I don't think you can really avoid network errors.

Comment: If the problem comes from the outside, the only thing you can do is control it in managing related exception. A `try except` statement could do the job, why not a loop to wait for an answer (but be very careful to plan a way to exit, or not to wait forever, if the server you try to reach is down)

Comment: I add a parameter: 'headrs' when I use 'requests.get()',much better now